# Timer method wont trigger when inside the method

Tags: c#, timer

I have a method called

```
public void OnCaptured(CaptureResult captureResult){}
```

Inside of these method i want to call the timer, I tried to enable the timer but it wont trigger at all, i also try to create another method and call it inside the method above to call the timer tick and again doesn't work at all.

here is my timer code:

```
private void TimeCountDown_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = int.Parse(lblCount.Text) -1;
    InvokeCD(count.ToString());
     if (count < 0) {
       TimeCountDown.Enabled = false;
       InvokeCD("5");
     }
}
```

Comment: **Which** timer are you using? There are at least 3 `Timer` classes in the .NET Framework and they're all quite different. I suspect you're using the [Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) one. If that's correct, one possible issue is that the timer has to run your code on the UI thread. If you've tied up the UI thread in some other task, the timer won't fire.

Comment: Oh man you beat me by 30 seconds :P

Comment: yes i am using the timer from Windows form. how am i going to trigger it? and yes the form i doing other task.

Comment: You need to move the CPU bound work off of the UI thread. You may be able to do this by creating a new `Task` or there may be an opportunity to add asynchronous activity here. Impossible to tell because we don't know the nature of that code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call Start() method to get the timer working. Setting up the property Enabled to true isn´t enough.

This HAS to work:

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000); //it will run every one second

public void OnCaptured(CaptureResult captureResult)
{
     timer.Elapsed += TimeCountDown_Tick;
     timer.Start();
}

private void TimeCountDown_Tick(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
 {
    int count = int.Parse(lblCount.Text) -1;
    InvokeCD(count.ToString());
     if (count < 0) {
       TimeCountDown.Enabled = false;
       InvokeCD("5");
     }
}
```

Comment: OP is using the `Timer` from WinForms not `System.Timers`

Comment: They're using `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`. If they switch to `System.Timers.Timer` that'll allow the timer to fire, but then they'll be in the world of hurt that is accessing UI elements from a different thread. And they can't help themselves by `Invoke`ing, since the whole reason that their original code didn't work is because they're keeping the UI thread busy.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever haha I beat you that time :P

Comment: i revise my code and this is working just like the way i wanted and thank you.

Comment: @Denver - you may think this is fixed but all you've done is replaced an obvious bug with a subtle one (unless you've also removed all access to UI elements from your timer code).

Comment: His `InvokeCD` calls are named such that there is a chance the cross thread access is being handled correctly, but we can't tell for sure from the listed code.